# Marquee & Alternatives

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, marquee

Another question(s) from design class 101.

I am using the Marquee tag for scrolling text for prototyping purposes.

A: How can I get the text to pre-load on the page and then start moving. 
   (Versus coming in at the sides of the screen to begin)

B: What is the best alternative (and the purest replacement) to move away from Marquee that will     accomplish A? a simple example would be beyond cool.

Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AN39F/

Comment: The genius of negative values. Thank you!  Also, if I did an onload instead of onclick, would the marquee begin as the page was loaded. Thanks again!

Comment: wrapping the IIFE function in window.onload instead of click would start the function when the window loads, yes!

Comment: Just CSS - http://jsfiddle.net/4mJQ6/2/. Can add other browser support to it

Comment: Adeneo: Thank you. This is working, but how do I get the text to be a single line of continuously running data (as not to have the reloading white space). Also to use multiple moving streams would I switch the script to be identified/executed by class rather than id?

Comment: Aravind: thank you for the alternative view. Everyone has been a great help. Quick question: Is there a way start the text on screen instead of coming in from the left corner? (Basically would like lets say 10 words across the page unload that then automatically start cycling across the page and reloading.