# Html <marquee> tag is preventing to display data in Android WebView

Tags: android, html, webview

I want to display some text with continuous moving behavior in webview. When I use marquee tag in html, then the webview doesn't show any data or text. But without the marquee tag it show's data/text. How can I solve this issue ?

Please note that, I am suffering with this problem in Nexus and Samsung devices with kitkat and lollypop version of android.

Here is my java code:

```
String tickerString = "<html><body><marquee>"+someTextIncludingHtmlAndCSS+"</marquee></body></html>";
WebView tickerWebView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.tickerWebView);
tickerWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
tickerWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
tickerWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,tickerString ,"text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Here is the XML code for WebView:

```
<WebView
            android:id="@+id/tickerWebView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#ffffff" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The marquee tag is known to possibly not work in all cases. To quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee):

> **Non-standard**
>   This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

But, if you still want to use it, [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546901/marquee-alternatives#comment34316222_22546901) should help:

> Just CSS - http://jsfiddle.net/4mJQ6/2. Can add other browser support to it

The fiddle is reproduced below:

```css
p.marquee{
    -webkit-animation-name: marquee;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-duration:10s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


@-webkit-keyframes marquee{
    0%{
        text-indent: 95%;
}
    100%{
        text-indent: -20%;  
    }
}
```

```html
<marquee>wow old school marquee</marquee>
<p class='marquee'>wow css3 marquee fun!</p>
```

Comment: Then what is the alternative for this tag? or how can I achieve my goal